# Docker Buildx fails to create builder in Windows

Tags: windows, docker, buildx, multiarch

I want to create a multi-architechture (Windows/Linux) image. I can't do this with Docker Desktop in Linux Containers, because it fails the build when it comes to Windows specific commands in the Dockerfile.

So I run Docker Desktop in Windows Containers. But when I want to **create** a builder with buildx, it fails without showing a reason. It just says `=> ERROR [internal] booting buildkit`. But if I continue and try to **build** the image, I get the same error again but with some extra info: `[internal] booting buildkit: ------ ERROR: Error response from daemon: Windows does not support privileged mode`.

Here is some output to show my situation:

```
C:\Windows\Temp>docker buildx stop

C:\Windows\Temp>docker buildx version
github.com/docker/buildx v0.10.3 79e156beb11f697f06ac67fa1fb958e4762c0fab

C:\Windows\Temp>docker buildx create --platform windows/x86_64,linux/x86_64 --name mybuilder --driver docker-container --bootstrap --use
[+] Building 1.2s (1/1) FINISHED
 => ERROR [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                              1.2s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                                 1.2s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_mybuilder0                                                                               0.0s
------
 > [internal] booting buildkit:
------
mybuilder

C:\Windows\Temp>docker buildx ls
NAME/NODE         DRIVER/ENDPOINT                STATUS   BUILDKIT PLATFORMS
mybuilder *       docker-container
  mybuilder0      npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine inactive          windows/amd64*, linux/amd64*
default           docker
  default         default                        running  20.10.23 windows/amd64, linux/amd64
desktop-windows   docker
  desktop-windows desktop-windows                running  20.10.23 windows/amd64, linux/amd64

C:\Windows\Temp>docker buildx inspect
Name:          mybuilder
Driver:        docker-container
Last Activity: 2023-07-18 22:34:08 +0000 UTC

Nodes:
Name:      mybuilder0
Endpoint:  npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine
Status:    inactive
Platforms: windows/amd64*, linux/amd64*

C:\Windows\Temp>docker buildx build --platform=windows/x86_64,linux/x86_64 --push --tag aspnet-node:v1803-v18.16.1 -f Dockerfile .
[+] Building 1.1s (1/1) FINISHED
 => ERROR [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                              1.1s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                                 1.1s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_mybuilder0                                                                               0.0s
------
 > [internal] booting buildkit:
------
ERROR: Error response from daemon: Windows does not support privileged mode

C:\Windows\Temp>docker buildx rm
mybuilder removed
```